# props not available in component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to implement my first react/redux/thunk test dispatch message. However I fail to understand why the "press" function fails to find the props.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
    at press (stuffList.js:17)

This will work perfectly fine in the componentWillMount() but it will not work when I click the button. Can someone clarify for me?

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as stuffActions from '../actions/stuffActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

class stuffList extends React.Component {



componentWillMount() {
    //this.props.stuffActions.fetchStuff();
    this.props.stuffActions.test();

}

press() {
    this.props.stuffActions.test();
}

renderData(item) {
    return <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>;
}

render() {

        return (

            <div className="">
            {this.props.data}
            <button onClick={this.press}>Click</button>


            </div>
        )
    }

}

stuffList.propTypes = {
    stuffActions: PropTypes.object,
    stuff: PropTypes.array
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        data: state.stuff
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
       stuffActions: bindActionCreators(stuffActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(stuffList);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your component context to the handler:

```
<button onClick={this.press.bind(this)}>Click</button>
```